# Import primitive types to layout with data binding library

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I need one separate boolean variable within my item layout, which is intended to use as a row of `recyclerView`, to toggle the state of some views inside it.

I know, I have got an option to include that boolean into my model class and use that. I am just curious whether it is possible to use primitive types inside layout with the help of data binding library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, it's possible and easy.

```
 <data>
        <variable
            name="someBoolean"
            type="boolean" />

        <variable
            name="someInt"
            type="int" /> 

        <variable
            name="someWrapperBoolean"
            type="java.lang.Boolean" />

        <variable
            name="someWrapperInt"
            type="java.lang.Integer" />
    </data>
```